# What are the most popular RSS readers? (software/web apps)

Tags: rss

I'm creating an application that generates RSS feeds that include an <enclosure> (for showing an audio player).

Since RSS readers are kinda flaky, in my experience, I'd like to test how my feeds look in as many readers as possible.

I only use Google Reader. What other RSS readers (websites or installable apps, for Windows, Linux AND Mac) are popular? Which are the ones I **must** test on?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Edit: a more recent list (just one feed, so might not represent population) is at http://pelfusion.com/tools/top-11-feed-readers-and-aggregators/

here's a helpful list from http://www.internetnews.com/xSP/article.php/3458291

A few years old, but possibly a good start

Aggregator Name (Market Share Percentage)

1. Bloglines (32.86%)
2. NetNewsWire (16.95%)
3. Firefox Live Bookmarks (7.78%)
4. Pluck (7.20%)
5. NewsGator Online(4.45%)
6. (not identified) (4.07%)*
7. FeedDemon (3.83%)
8. SharpReader (3.27%)
9. My Yahoo (2.58%)
10. iPodder (2.42%)
11. NewsGator (2.23%)
12. Thunderbird (2.13%)
13. RSS Bandit (1.12%)
14. NewsFire (1.05%)
15. iPodderX (1.02%)
16. Sage (0.71%)
17. FeedReader (0.67%)
18. RssReader (0.54%)
19. LiveJournal (0.46%)
20. Opera RSS Reader (0.45%)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the information on  these links will help you:

- [email.about](http://email.about.com/od/rssreaderswin/tp/top_rss_windows.htm)
- [feed-readers](http://www.feed-readers.com/most-popular-rss-readers.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Top 9 Windows RSS Feed Readers:
NewzCrawler, FeedDemon, Omea Reader, Bloglines,  NewsGator Online Services, NewsGator Inbox for Outlook, Awasu and SharpReader are the most popular RSS readers.

edit: according to http://email.about.com/od/rssreaderswin/tp/top_rss_windows.htm

Answer (score 1):

Web: Bloglines: http://bloglines.com/

Mac OS X: NetNewsWire: http://www.newsgator.com/INDIVIDUALS/NETNEWSWIRE/

Windows: SharpReader: http://www.sharpreader.net/

Linux: Liferea: http://liferea.sourceforge.net/